# Getting key with a list of arrays

Tags: php, laravel-5

How do i get the key of the Year-month return by my query:

```
array:5 [▼
  "2017 - Jan" => array:1 [▶]
  "2017 - Feb" => array:2 [▶]
  "2017 - Mar" => array:3 [▶]
  "2017 - Apr" => array:6 [▶]
  "2017 - May" => array:30 [▶]
]
```

I tried using this method but it returns an error:

```
foreach($yearly_incentives as $key => $yearly_incentive) {
    $tourist_yearly_incentive_list->year_month = key($yearly_incentive[$key]); 
}
```

and gives me an error 'Undefined index: 2017 - Jan'

Comment: What is your exact need? Desired output?

Comment: `key($yearly_incentive[$key]);` makes no sense, when you pass `$key` to the array. You could use $key instead of the whole call.

Comment: But I don't think that'll fix the problem. Please provide more information

Comment: $key is undefined as far as we can tell. Please include the actual loop definition instead of `foreach(.....)`. Also, it looks like that loop would just overwrite `->year_month` repeatedly. Can you edit the question to add more explanation of the problem?

Comment: i posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys my question is not readable. but here's my answer:

```
$new_list = [];
foreach ($yearly_incentives as $key => $yearly_incentive) {
   $tourist_yearly_incentive_list = new \stdClass();

   $tourist_yearly_incentive_list->year_month = key($yearly_incentives);
   $new_list[] = $tourist_yearly_incentive_list;

   next($yearly_incentives);
}
```

I was trying to get the Year and Month of the given keys that I queried.